# IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite with web service exceptions

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have an HTTPS redirect set up in a URL Rewrite. Everything works but I need to exclude some server ports for web services that are not going to be included in the SSL.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="1010" />
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="1212" />
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When I add the server port exception, the web services work but I don't get my redirect on the http calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a missing attribute....

```
<add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="1010" negate="true"\>
```